# Scala type mismatch in function which returns Double => String when "return" keyword is used

Tags: scala

I have a function which returns a `Double => String` function in Scala. When I add the `return`s at the end of the function, I get a `type mismatch`:

```
type mismatch; found : String required: Double ⇒ String
```

Why is this the case? Isn't `return` purely optional in Scala? In this scenario, everything is fine when I delete the two `return`s, but what would I do if I wanted to return somewhere before that if/else?

```
def createBuckets(start: Double, end: Double, gap: Double): Double => String = {
  var buckets: List[String] = List[String]()
  val endPoints: List[Double] = List[Double]()

  var first = start
  var second = gap
  while (second < end) {
    buckets ::= first + " to " + second 
    first = second
    second += gap
  }
  if (first != end) {
    buckets ::= first + " to " + end 
  }
  buckets = buckets.reverse
  println("BUCKETS: " + buckets)

  val range = end - start

  (input: Double) => {
    val bucket = (input / gap).floor.toInt
    if (input == end) {
      // Type mismatch from this return
      return buckets(buckets.size - 1)
    } else {
      // and this one
      return buckets(bucket)
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: remove `return` statement from both `if` and `else`. As you are adding `return` you are forcefully returning that value.

Comment: Okay, but what would I do if I wanted to return somewhere before that final if/else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simplified version of your error:

```
 def foo: Int => Int = { x => return x } //error
```

Note that `return` is only used in methods definitions.  It is not usually valid in anonymous functions.  This syntactic error is clearer if you try declaring a `val` instead:

```
val foo: Int => Int = { x => return x }
//error: return outside method definition
```

You can read more about the difference between methods and functions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala).

Even in method bodies, `return` is almost always unidiomatic in Scala, and is generally avoided.  If you want to return before the final `if-else`, you can wrap the whole block in another `if-else`, or instantiate a `val` and make the last statement of the expression the `val` (e.g. `{ val x = 5; ...; x }`).

Comment: `not valid syntax`: `def f: Int =  ((x: Int) => return x)(42)`. It has a niche role: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/collection/IterableLike.scala#L160

Comment: @som-snytt I stand corrected – I don't think I've seen that use in an anonymous function before.  And I agree that it has a niche role to break certain control structures prematurely.

Answer (score 3):

If for some reason a return was called for:

```
def outer(): Int => String = {
  def f(i: Int): String = { if (i < 0) return "BAD" ; "hello" take i }
  f
}
```

Your only hangup is that you want to return a function with minimal boilerplate.

This is just a compiler bug, but it's pretty funny:

```
object X { def f(i: Int = return 42) = i * 2 }
```

Answer (score 2):

`return` returns from your `def`, not your anonymous function. Hence the type error. Now, as stated in other answers, in your case you could simply remove it:

```
if (input == end) {
  buckets(buckets.size - 1)
} else {
  // and this one
  buckets(bucket)
}
```

You don't need early return statements, and in general you can structure any code to have a single return point.

For example a common pattern in imperative languages:

```
def sillyExample(input) {
  if (input.isBad) {
    return None
  } 

  //some complex operations go here
  return Some(complexResult);
}
```

This can be rewritten as:

```
def sillyExample(input) {
  if (input.isBad) {
    None
  } else {
   //some complex operations go here
   Some(complexResult);
  }
}
```

That is no more complex. The extra level of indentation for the happy-path code can be annoying (and can be solved by higher functional abstractions but I digress), but you get used to it very quickly. The advantage on not having arbitrary `return` statements, and focusing on expressions instead is that it brings you a step closer to referential transparency

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the return keywords because they forcefully return a result from the createBuckets function and you get a type mismatch error because the returned type is a String (the bucket), not a function from Double to String.
Using the return keyword is not idiomatic scala and you should try to avoid it.
I hope this helps.

Comment: What would I do if I wanted to return a different value in my anonymous function somewhere before that final if/else?